# Embedding an HTML Audio Element

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3, wamp

I want to embed an Audio file in an HTML page. Below is the code I am using.

```
<audio controls height='100' width='100'>
    <source src='C:/wamp/www/Music/Tracks/Sweater&nbsp;Weather.MP3' type='audio/mpeg'>
    <embed height='50' width='100' src='C:/wamp/www/Music/Tracks/Sweater&nbsp;Weather.MP3'>
</audio>
```

When I run the HTML page, the audio element shows up but it is blank and no music can be played. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you hosting your webpage online or is it stored locally on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an absolute path from your computer. You have to upload the music file and put an relative link in the embed. Also, try to use underscores in your file instead of space. For example, if you upload it to the same folder you're executing this piece of code, it would be this;

```
<audio controls height='100' width='100'>
    <source src='Sweater_Weather.MP3' type='audio/mpeg'>
    <embed height='50' width='100' src='Sweater_Weather.MP3'>
</audio>
```

Comment: I renamed the MP3 file to Sweater_Weather.MP3 and I used the above code, however the same problem persists. How do you upload the music file and put a relative link in the embed?

Comment: The server is local to my machine so do I still need to upload the file?

Comment: Are you running the HTML locally? If so, you could just use your own code, with a minor change;

<audio controls height='100' width='100'>
    <source src='C:/wamp/www/Music/Tracks/Sweater_Weather.MP3' type='audio/mpeg'>
    <embed height='50' width='100' src='C:/wamp/www/Music/Tracks/Sweater_Weather.MP3'>
</audio>

Answer (score 0):

```
&nbsp;
```

in HTML will print a space character in text for the user.

If you're resolving a URL, you'll want the URL encoding which is %20, e.g.:

```
<audio controls height='100' width='100'>
  <source src='C:/wamp/www/Music/Tracks/Sweater%20Weather.MP3' type='audio/mpeg'>
  <embed height='50' width='100' src='C:/wamp/www/Music/Tracks/Sweater%20Weather.MP3'>
</audio>
```

Comment: I tried the code above, however, the same problem exists. I have a feeling it has to do with the "/" or it has something to do with the file location (Although the file path specified above is the right one).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload the file. It has to do with your path. Make sure that the path you are pointing to is relative to where your local site is being hosted (through wamp).

For example, if your site is located in C:\wamp\www\ your source would be src='Music/Tracks/Sweater Weather.MP3'

A space is allowed in the filename.

Edit:

```
<audio controls>
   <source src='Tracks/Sweater Weather.MP3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
```

Comment: Where, locally, is your site located?

Comment: its in the Music folder

Comment: See my post edit above. If your site is in the music folder, you should be using the above...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<head></head>
<body>
<audio controls height='100' width='100'>
    <source src='C:/.../..../..../sample_music.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

please check the name of your file, instead of a blank space, use an underscore to join the words followed by the extension in the song name itself, the above piece of code works perfectly at my end